# Google-amp-cache caches the image with changed dimension why?

Tags: amp-html

When Google AMP caches the image, it changes the dimensions. See this image https://cdn.ampproject.org/i/s/rentzeal.com/img/index.jpeg
it has the dimensions 1139x1820
whereas the original image https://rentzeal.com/img/index.jpeg
had the dimensions of 2002x3199

This is the main cause of my prblm, Is there a way to avoid this dimension change?

Comment: per @abielita, have you tried `srcset=" "` That approach should insure that the appropriate image is displayed on the target device. Showing a device-independent image here does not address the real issue: showing your image(s) from the CDN on a target device.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an expected behavior. Based from this [Cache optimizations and modifications](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#cache-optimizations-and-modifications) documentation, the Google AMP Cache performs optimizations and modifications, such as the following:

- Validates content is truly in AMP format, meeting all AMP performance goals.
- Caches images and fonts in addition to AMP documents.
- **Limits maximum image dimensions to prevent browser memory issues and poor responsiveness.**

Comment: So @abielita can you suggest me alternative way to serve the image, So that Google cache do not able to cache it, as dimension change will effect my page view as it is an sprite image, and it has predefined css accordingly.

Comment: One workaround would be to break up the image into non-sprite versions. The images will be served over HTTP2 on the AMP Cache, reducing the need for sprites.